# Using rvest package when HTML table has two headers

Tags: r, dataframe, rvest

I am using the following code to scrape an HTML table on AFL player data:

```
library(rvest)

website <-read_html("https://afltables.com/afl/stats/teams/adelaide/2017_gbg.html")
table   <- website %>%
           html_nodes("table") %>%
           .[(1)] %>%
           html_table()
```

The resulting table is 34 obs. of 27 variables, however `nrow(table)` or `ncol(table)` both return NULL. Is it correct that this is because there are two rows of headers in the dataframe? I want to be able to do calculations based on individual columns however the following gives an error:

```
table[,1]
# Error in table[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Which does it produce this error and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(rvest)
#> Le chargement a nécessité le package : xml2

website <-read_html("https://afltables.com/afl/stats/teams/adelaide/2017_gbg.html")
```

On this website, you have several tables, one per link displayed above
the printed table on the main page. 
Using `html_tables` on the result of `html_nodes("tables")` allows you to get all the tables in a list at once.

```r
all_tables <- website %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table()

str(all_tables, 1)
#> List of 23
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  27 variables:
```

You can then select the table you want but the header are still not
right

```r
head(all_tables[[1]])
#>          Disposals Disposals Disposals Disposals Disposals Disposals
#> 1           Player        R1        R2        R3        R4        R5
#> 2     Atkins, Rory        19        19        19        23        29
#> 3  Beech, Jonathon                                                  
#> 4     Betts, Eddie        18        13        16        22        12
#> 5      Brown, Luke        18        12        13         9        15
#> 6 Cameron, Charlie        23        17        16        16        13
#>   Disposals Disposals Disposals Disposals Disposals Disposals Disposals
#> 1        R6        R7        R8        R9       R10       R11       R12
#> 2        23        20        21        28        37        14        25
#> 3                                                                    15
#> 4        16        13         9        16        14        12        11
#> 5        17        13        20        25        16        12          
#> 6        13        14        10        18        13         8        13
#>   Disposals Disposals Disposals Disposals Disposals Disposals Disposals
#> 1       R14       R15       R16       R17       R18       R19       R20
#> 2        28        15        23        18        19        16        16
#> 3        12        11                                                  
#> 4        14        11        13        16         8                  16
#> 5        10        15        14        17        11        10        20
#> 6        15                  10        20         6         9        17
#>   Disposals Disposals Disposals Disposals Disposals Disposals Disposals
#> 1       R21       R22       R23        QF        PF        GF       Tot
#> 2        27        21        21        16        22        17       536
#> 3                                                                    38
#> 4         7        16        12        13        13         7       318
#> 5        17        17         9        20        10        13       353
#> 6        13        10        10        15        19        16       334
```

Using some manipulation on the list and tables with `purrr` and `dplyr`,
you can format your table which has 2 headers:

```r
all_tables   <- website %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  # do not let httr handles header automatically. 
  html_table(header = FALSE)

library(purrr)
#> 
#> Attachement du package : 'purrr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:rvest':
#> 
#>     pluck
all_tables <- all_tables %>%
  # get the first column, first row to set the name for the list elements
  # pluck is a purrr function acting like x[[1]][1, 1] here
  lmap( ~ set_names(.x, nm = pluck(.x, 1, 1, 1))) %>%
  # For each table, set second line as header 
  # and delete first and second line
  map(~ set_names(.x, nm = .x[2, ]) %>% slice(-c(1, 2)))
str(all_tables_res, 1)
#> List of 23
#>  $ Disposals              :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ Kicks                  :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ Marks                  :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ Handballs              :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ Goals                  :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ Behinds                :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ Hit Outs               :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ Tackles                :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ Rebounds               :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ Inside 50s             :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ Clearances             :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ Clangers               :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ Frees                  :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ Frees Against          :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ Brownlow Votes         :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ Contested Possessions  :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ Uncontested Possessions:Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ Contested Marks        :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ Marks Inside 50        :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ One Percenters         :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ Bounces                :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ Goal Assists           :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:
#>  $ % Played               :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  27 variables:

You can now called any table of the website.

head(all_tables_res$Goals)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 27
#>             Player    R1    R2    R3    R4    R5    R6    R7    R8    R9
#>              <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     Atkins, Rory     3     1     -     2     1     -     1     1     -
#> 2  Beech, Jonathon                                                      
#> 3     Betts, Eddie     4     3     3     6     3     1     3     2     3
#> 4      Brown, Luke     -     1     -     -     1     -     -     -     -
#> 5 Cameron, Charlie     2     1     -     1     2     2     2     -     4
#> 6     Crouch, Brad                             -     -     -     -     1
#> # ... with 17 more variables: R10 <chr>, R11 <chr>, R12 <chr>, R14 <chr>,
#> #   R15 <chr>, R16 <chr>, R17 <chr>, R18 <chr>, R19 <chr>, R20 <chr>,
#> #   R21 <chr>, R22 <chr>, R23 <chr>, QF <chr>, PF <chr>, GF <chr>,
#> #   Tot <chr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, and unrelated to your question: Don't use `table` as a name for your objects, because this name is already reserved for other functionalities in `R`. It is considered bad practice and I've been told that it will come back and nip you in the butt somewhere down the line.

Moving on to the question: You are struggling with the type of data that `html_table()` gives you. You are returned a list, which contains a regular data.frame. The list you outputted, has `NULL` for the number of columns and rows, because that list only has *one* element: the data.frame. By selecting that first (and only) element of your list, you will get to the dataframe you're actually interesting in. This dataframe has 27 columns and 34 rows

```
website <-read_html("https://afltables.com/afl/stats/teams/adelaide/2017_gbg.html")
scraped <- website %>%
                html_nodes("table") %>%
                .[(1)] %>%
                html_table() %>%
                `[[`(1)   # Select the first element of the list, like scraped[[1]]
ncol(scraped) 
# 27
nrow(scraped)
# 34
```

Comment: The first bit is misinformation and shld be removed or clarified. R is _plenty_ smart enough to still be able to call `table()` even when there's a `table` variable that isn't a function (e.g. `table <- c(2, 1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1) ; table(table)`).  It's not "overwritten". It's still a bad practice and not a good idea in general, but not for the reasons you state.

Comment: Thanks for calling that out @hrbrmstr. Out of interest, do you happened to have a source that explains how and why R is plenty smart enough to distinguish? If R is really that clever, then it seems like the main (only?) reason to avoid names like `list`, `data` and `c` is for the programmers to not get confused, since R seems to be dealing with it just fine.